# If you use "long long" in C language, you will get an error

Tags: c

Why does the program turn off when you write 'long long', and why does the program turn on when you write 'long'?

Here's the code question below.
->One for 1, two for 2, three for 3. Like this. 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5... Create this sequence and give a certain section to find the sum of the sections.
In the first line, integers A and B (1<=A<=B<=1000) representing the start and end of the section are given. That is, the sum from the Ath number to the Bth number in the sequence can be obtained.

ex)if A=3, B=7
->answer=15

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){
    int a,b,c,s=0,i,j,k,p=0;
    int n[500500];  
    scanf("%d %d",&a,&b);
    for (i=1;i<=1000;i++){ 
        c=s;
        s+=i;
        for (j=c;j<s;j++)
            n[j]=i;
    }
    for (k=a;k<=b;k++)
        p+=n[k-1];
    printf("%d",p);
}
```

Comment: Write `long long` where exactly? Please post a [mcve].

Comment: `int n[500500]` allocates 4 · 500500 bytes on the stack. That's a lot, but your system can do it. Using `long long` will double the amount of bytes, which your system can't do. You've blown the stack by just calling `main`. If you need large amounts of memory, use dynamic allocation on the heap.

Answer (score 3):

Here:

```
int n[500500]
```

you allocate 4 · 500500 bytes on the stack; typically each `int` used 4 bytes.. That's a lot, but your system can do it. Using `long long` (which is usually 8 bytes long) instead of `int` will double the amount of bytes, which your system can't do. You've blown the stack by just calling `main`.

If you need large amounts of memory, use dynamic allocation on the heap. (But I imagine that there's a solution to your problem that doesn't need a large array at all, just triangular numbers. But even if you use an array, it is enough to make it 1000 ints long. According to your description, 1000 is the maximum index into this array, not the maximum value of an array element.)

Answer (score 0):

```
int n[500500];
```

This line will reserve 500500 `int`s on the automatic storage.
The automatic storage is very limited in size. On your system, `int` is probably 4 bytes big. That means you reserve 500500 * 4 = 2002000 Bytes = ~2002 KB on the automatic storage.

if you change it to `long long`, which is probably 8 bytes on your system, you simply double the memory needed to just hold that array.

What you should do is using dynamic storage instead :

```
int* n = malloc(500500*sizeof(*n));
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but I originally used "long long n[500500]" but it didn't work at this time. So, I used another "long" or "int", not long long. Why can't I use long long?

Comment: @saiam12 long long >= long >= int.
On your platform, int and long are the same size (4 bytes), long long is 8 bytes

Answer (score -1):

It's not clear which variable you want to be (I assume) a 64-bit integer, but there's nothing inherently wrong with this code.

If `int` is 32-bits on your system, you'll use a little over 2 megabytes of memory for this program. If you switched it to `long long` (64-bits), then it would take 4 megabytes, which again, should not be a problem.

Your program, will, however, do bad things if a and b don't make sense. There's no reason to use `long long` for this program as it is written. The maximum output is 333,832,500 which is less than the maximum 32-bit integer 2,147,483,647. If the `long long` isn't working, then we need to know more about your environment and compiler.